# Using a Custom Android Library with Maven and ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, adt, m2eclipse

I'm new in Maven, and i was trying to use it in my Android projects.
I have ADT, and i have installed the m2e plugin for Eclipse.
With a right click, i have converted the project in a Maven Project, and i have replaced (almost) all the jar libraries file with Maven.
Now i am trying to run my project, that uses a custom library project (using Maven too), but i am getting, everytime i change the pom, a new error.

This is the pom of my library:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>com.my.artifact.id</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>


<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-rc.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                    <platform>10</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    [All my dependencies in Maven]
</dependencies>
```

and this is the pom file of my project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.my.project.groupid</groupId>
<artifactId>com.my.project.artifactid</artifactId>
<version>0.4</version>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>com.my.group.id</groupId>
         <artifactId>com.my.artifact.id</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    [All other dependencies]
</dependencies>


<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-rc.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                    <platform>10</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now, with this configuration i have this error when i try to launch the app:

```
[2014-09-26 09:45:44 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;
[2014-09-26 09:45:44 - MyProjectName] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;
```

That is a library used by one of my dependency.
In both project, in Properties --> Build Path --> Order and Export i have only checked Maven dependencies.

But, if i try to uncheck this in both of the project, i can run the application, but when i try to instantiate a class of my library project, the app crashes with this error:

```
09-26 10:08:16.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 10:08:16.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 2023
09-26 10:08:16.318: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.myapp.MyExampleClassTask
```

On deploy and on start, my app logcat print this on:

```
09-26 10:05:44.318: W/dalvikvm(2023): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/myapp/MyExampleClassTask; (30)
09-26 10:05:44.318: W/dalvikvm(2023): Link of class 'Lcom/example/myapp/MyExampleClassTask;' failed
09-26 10:05:44.318: E/dalvikvm(2023): Could not find class 'com.example.myapp.MyExampleClassTask', referenced from method com.example.myapp.MainFragment$1.onClick
09-26 10:05:44.318: W/dalvikvm(2023): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 68 (Lcom/example/myapp/MyExampleClassTask;) in Lcom/example/myapp/MainFragment$1;
```

MyExampleClassTask is a class that extends a class of my library.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're missing the packaging type `apklib` from your Android Library POM *and* in your Android App Maven dependencies:

```
<groupId>com.my.group.id</groupId>
<artifactId>com.my.artifact.id</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<packaging>apklib</packaging>
```

So that your POM looks something like [this](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/blob/1d309d6ed2bb6b8fb9b3cac9ac1036c776a7a2b7/src/test/projects/libraryprojects/libraryprojects-apklib1/pom.xml)

Also you need you Android Library checked out into the local Eclipse workspace for the ADT to find and compile the source code.

Comment: If i add the <packaging> tag with apklib, i got an error. It seems that can't find the type apklib.

Comment: Have you tried running a Maven -> Update Project... ?

Comment: I have tried multiple times...nothing... the error is like "Project build error: Unknown packaging: apklib"

Comment: You could post a gist of your updated POM or someting.